# How to design a book library application

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating an app for a library. I need to create a database containing details about all the books in the library and the members in the library. I need to maintain a table that connects a person with the books he has read. Each book has a unique id as well the member. I need to track each book taken by the person and recommend books based on his interests. Also i have to track the time required by the person to complete a book. I have only basic knowledge about databases and that too about MySQL only. If I'm right you cannot have multiple values for a field in MySQL. I thought of creating a table for mapping a person with the books he/she has lended. But the problem with such an approach is that the size of the table increases uncontrollably. Is there any other approach that I'm missing that can make my database simpler? I need to frequently search for content from the database. So the table must be as small as possible.

I'm also ready to learn any other language other than MySQL if my requirement is not accomplished by it.

Comment: Is the library unable to use existing library automation software such as [Koha](http://www.koha.org/)?

Comment: I believe koha is based on perl and is a web based software. The library software I'm creating is based on java and has several custom features to be added. I have little knowledge about perl. So wont be able to debug or provide support to library system based on koha.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach would indeed be to create a "join" table that maps people to books.  Such a table may have many rows, but each row should only consist of a few columns -- person id, book id, timestamp loaned, timestamp completed.

It is not uncommon to have MySQL tables with millions of rows.  Don't worry about that. Make sure to index the person id and book id, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have another question. If the database i'm creating contains millions of book and equally large number of people wont it slow down  the searching and retrieval process even if i index the person id and book id? Pardon me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sure, potentially.  If there are millions of books and millions of people, and every person borrows every book, the PersonBook mapping table could have trillions of rows. But that's probably not going to happen.  And indexing will speed those searches up dramatically. The bottom line is that, if there are that many book-person relationships, you're going to be storing that many pieces of data one way or another.  Storing them as separate rows in a table (rather than concatenating into single entries or some such) gives MySQL the greatest ability to help you search quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aproach`:` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33b45/1

You need three tables: books, members, lendings. The code is in the fiddle.